# Rust tuple assignment

Tags: rust

I have the following scenario:

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn add_one(px: BigUint, py: BigUint) -> (BigUint, BigUint) {
    (px+1u32, py+1u32)
}

fn test(x: &[u8], y: &[u8]) {
    let mut x = BigUint::from_bytes_le(x);
    let mut y = BigUint::from_bytes_le(y);

    (x,y) = add_one(x, y);
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following compile error:

```
error[E0658]: destructuring assignments are unstable
  --> src/lib.rs:76:11
   |
76 |     (x,y) = ecc_add(x, y);
   |     ----- ^
   |     |
   |     cannot assign to this expression
   |
   = note: see issue #71126 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71126> for more information
```

What does this mean? `let (x,y) = add_one(x, y);` seems to fix the error, but I think this will not mutate the original `x` and `y` variable (?) and I want to avoid creating any temporary variables. I get the same error when using `(x, y) = (x+1u32, y+1u32);`

If I instead use a single return value, it works fine:

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn add_one(px: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    px+1u32
}

fn test(x: &[u8]) {
    let mut x = BigUint::from_bytes_le(x);

    x = add_one(x)
}
```

---

How do I assign `x` and `y` to the return value of `add_one` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Rust version 1.59, this is a stable feature, and your original implementation will work. See here for more information: https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/02/24/Rust-1.59.0.html#destructuring-assignments.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Destructuring assignments like that are an unstable feature, prone to changes and removal, so you cannot use it in stable rust.</strike> Destructuring assignment is now stable.

Just use `let (x,y) = ...`. "Too many temporary variables" is not a concern you should be worrying about (without profiling, at least), especially since the old `x` and `y` variables have been moved out of. Let the compiler worry about reusing space; it can do a better job than you can.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. In Rust especially, having a ton of local variables is entirely normal and a significant improvement over having to trace modifications to a single variable. As far as the compiler is concerned, the SSA-style variable use is likely *easier* to optimize around than tracing explicit mutations everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Using tuples in nested scopes**

At the time of writing, destructuring assignments is still an unstable feature, which means you can **not** set the x and y tuple values like this:

```
let x: String;

let y: String;

(x, y) = (String::from("red"), String::from("fire"));
```

You have to use **let** (x, y) like this:

```
let (x, y) = (String::from("red"), String::from("fire"));
```

However, in some cases you want to declare the tuple in a parent scope (so that you can use it in later code in the same scope), but you want the tuple values to be set in nested scopes - such as if-statements.

In these cases, you cannot use **let** in the nested scope to refer to the tuple values in the parent scope, because **let** creates a new tuple in the nested scope - instead of using/referencing the tuple in the parent scope.

However, you can still use **let** in the nested scopes to create new tuples; and then just **bump** them up to the parent scope at the end of each nested scope.

```
fn main() {

    let test_value = 1;

    // create (x1, y1) in outer scope
    let (x1, y1) = { 
        // create (x2, y2) in first nested scope
        let (x2, y2) = 
            if test_value == 1 {
                // create and set (x3, y3) in second nested scope
                let x3 = String::from("red"); 
                let y3 = String::from("fire");
                (x3, y3) // bump (x3, y3) values to (x2, y2) in first nested scope
            }
            else {
                panic!("Invalid value for test_value");
            };
        (x2, y2) // bump (x2, y2) values to (x1, y1) in outer scope
    };

    // Use the (x1, y1) values in the outer scope
    println!("x1: {:?} y1: {:?}", x1, y1);
}
```

**In Summary**

Code in a nested scope can refer to tuple values created in a parent scope, but it cannot change their values. The parent scope must **drag up** their values from the nested scope with **let** and the nested scope must **bump** the new values to the parent scope - as seen in the above example.

**In Summary - This compiles:**

```
let (a1, b1) = (7, 5);

if a1 > b1{
    print!("{} is larger than {}", a1, b1);
}
```

**In Summary - This does not compile:**

```
let (a1, b1) = (7, 5);

if a1 > b1{
    print!("{} is larger than {}", a1, b1);
    (a1, b1) = (10, 8);
}
```

**In Summary - This compiles:**

```
let (a1, b1) = (7, 5);
let (a1, b1) = 
    if 7 > 5{
        println!("{} is larger than {}", a1, b1); // original a1, b1 values
        (10, 20) // bump up new values to a1, b1
    }
    else { 
        // you need an else statement to make the entire if-statement deterministic,
        // otherwise you get expected...found errors
        panic!("What?");
    };
    
println!("a1: {:?} b1: {:?}", a1, b1); // new a1, b1 values
```

Output:

7 is larger than 5

a1: 10 b1: 20

Answer (score 0):

You need to destructure using let (shadowing variables is allowed and encouraged).

```rust
let (x, y) = add_one(x, y);
```